# Jquery css fadein text

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, fadein

I'm trying to fadein my text content in my horizontal slider. Actually, I want to fadein my text when I am in the #directions menu item. I tried something but it seems not working.

**[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jarod51/4RvWY/6/)**

in my HTML, I have a div tag with an id :

```
<div id="directions" class="panel">
        <h2>Directions</h2>
        
        <div id="test"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
    </div>
```

I defined this div id=test in my css like that:

```
#test p {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
       -moz-transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
         -o-transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
            transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
}

#test p.load {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

My Jquery:

```
$('#wrap').find('#test').removeClass('load');
                $target.addClass('load');
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ?
Regards,
Jarod.

Comment: Not an answer but I think all questions should be setup like this :)

Comment: @JoakimM this question is getting upvotes because of the slider :) but answer ..... wait..... not summarized so .... care to all code.... and get the answer later may be or :))  ... :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following

```
#test p.load{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

to this

```
.shown #test p{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4RvWY/8/

Comment: Thx koningdavid. Exactly what I was looking for. It works fine.

Comment: It seems that the effect works only once. I need that the effect repeats each time when I am under #directions. It works for my images but not for my text. Do you know what I need to change ?

Comment: @user979974 use .shown #test p instead of .load #test p, i updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

It should be much easier solution.

CSS:

```
#test p {
    display: none;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#test p').fadeIn(1000)
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tykpL/